# Using atexit to call pthread_exit

Tags: c++, pthreads, posix, language-lawyer

Is it legal to make `atexit` call `pthread_exit`? Without it when `main()` returns all the threads are terminated. (The trivial solution would be to modify `main()` to call `pthread_exit()` itself, but that's not possible in the instances this minimal example was derived from).

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

void *foo(void *data) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << "\n";
    sleep(1);
  }
  return NULL;
}

void foo_init() {
  std::atexit([](){
    pthread_exit(NULL);
  });
}

int main() {
  foo_init();
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
  pthread_t thr;
  pthread_create(&thr, &attr, foo, NULL);
}
```

The manpage for `pthread_exit` states:

> Thread termination does not release any application visible process resources, including, but not limited to, mutexes and file descriptors, nor does it perform any process level cleanup actions, including, but not limited to, calling any atexit() routines that may exist.

Which seems to rule out the risk of crazy recursion breaking things.

It also states:

> The behaviour of pthread_exit() is undefined if called from a cancellation cleanup handler or destructor function that was invoked as a result of either an implicit or explicit call to pthread_exit().

Which indicates there are places where it would be undefined to call `pthread_exit`, but (unless main takes > 10 seconds to return, which let's assume isn't possible in a "real" case) isn't applicable.

This example "works for me" but it is required to work by POSIX? If not is it undefined or unspecified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some problems as far as POSIX is concerned:

- the [docs for `pthread_exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_exit.html) says: "The process exits with an exit status of 0 after the last thread has been terminated. The behavior is as if the implementation called exit() with a zero argument at thread termination time"
- the [docs for `exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/exit.html) says, "If a function registered by a call to atexit() fails to return, the remaining registered functions shall not be called and the rest of the exit() processing shall not be completed. If exit() is called more than once, the behavior is undefined".

So strictly speaking, when `pthread_exit()` is called for the last thread, the behavior will be as if `exit()` were called more than once, which is to say it's undefined behavior.

That said, I imagine that the worst that should happen is that the application will crash or deadlock when the last thread exits. Since the process is exiting anyway, the risk may be acceptable depending on the nature of your application and to what level your testing indicates how low the risk might be.

If you can arrange to know which thread will be the last to exit, I think you could block on a semaphore, condition variable, or mutex in the `atexit()` callback instead of calling `pthread_exit()`.  Have the last thread release that block when it's about to call `pthread_exit()` (or return).